# Heat Map Seaborn fmt='d' error

Tags: python, pandas, annotations, seaborn

In extension to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086883/heat-maps-seaborn-annot-error/31086912#31086912)

I can plot the Heat map with Seaborn very well and with suggestion can get annotation. But I see a new problem now.

Input File

```
Nos,Place,Way,Name,00:00:00,12:00:00
123,London,Air,Apollo,342,972
123,London,Rail,Beta,2352,342
123,Paris,Bus,Beta,545,353
345,Paris,Bus,Rava,652,974
345,Rome,Bus,Rava,2325,56
345,London,Air,Rava,2532,9853
567,Paris,Air,Apollo,545,544
567,Rome,Rail,Apollo,5454,5
876,Japan,Rail,Apollo,644,54
876,Japan,Bus,Beta,45,57
876,Japan,Bus,Beta,40,57
876,Japan,Bus,Beta,40,57
```

Program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set()

df = pd.read_csv('heat_map_data.csv')

df3 = df.copy()
for c in ['Place','Name']:
    df3[c] = df3[c].astype('category')

sns.heatmap(df3.pivot_table(index='Place', columns='Name', values='00:00:00' ),annot=True, fmt='.1f' )

plt.show()
```

1. If I take `fmt='d'` then I get error of float value and changed to `fmt='f'` And I get the count of the desired column.

But When the same axis value repeats it does not add the count from desired column. Any solution for that pls ?

As it is seen in the input file

```
876,Japan,Bus,Beta,45,57
876,Japan,Bus,Beta,40,57
876,Japan,Bus,Beta,40,57
```

It has 3 rows in repeat and the value of them should be shown as sum 
the cell which represents `Japan` and `Beta` should annot value as `125` instead it shows `41.7`. How do I achieve that? Also is it possible to give two values as annotation ?

[image]

2. Second  doubt is now that in `pivot` I am giving `value='00:00:00'` but I need it to dynamically read the last column from the file.

Comment: what do you mean by *dynamically read the last column from the file*? value is the second last column and you do read it in

Comment: The file is to be updated at every interval of time and an new column of counts is generated (Previous data processing part) and that new column is to be plotted after the data process in every interval of time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [aggfunc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) keyword passing in a dict:

**aggfunc :**

> function, default numpy.mean, or list of functions
>   If list of functions passed, the resulting pivot table will have hierarchical columns whose top level are the function names (inferred from the function objects themselves)

```
sns.heatmap(df3.pivot_table(index='Place', columns='Name', 
values='00:00:00',aggfunc={'00:00:00':np.sum}), annot=True, fmt='.1f')
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Comment: @PadraicCunningham May I have a suitable solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073889/operations-on-columns-multiple-files-pandas